# iOS unwind to view not loaded

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, segue, stack-unwinding

I'm in front of a little problem :

I have something like that when launching the app :

(1) Splash view --> I am logged ? --> (3) HomeView | else (2) Login view

So when I log, then I go to the home view. And when I logout, I can unwind to the login view because i came from it.

**BUT** if I don't pass from the login view and redirect directly to the home view, I can't unwind to login view when logout.

Someone know a solution about this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just put my logic here:
Take/add one viewController such like, `DummyViewController` as `rootViewController` of your app.
in the `DummyViewController's` `viewWillAppear` method put logic like a

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if(login == YES)
    {
       //go to home screen
    }
    else
    {
      // go to login screen
    }
}
```

In `DummyViewController` you just need to write code in `viewWillAppear` not anymore.
If you want to **Logout**  then just call

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

And `viewWillAppear` method of `DummyViewController` will manage your screen based on **login** status.

Comment: I tried it but I'm going to the rootviewcontroller, and after, it redirect well in LoginView. It's good. But there isn't a way to redirect directly to the LoginView ?

Comment: There are many ways, but i am thinking about above trick, it easy to manage between login and logout :)

Comment: Also you can manage it with nice animation when login screen or logout screen is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSNotificationCenter` to notify your root class when logout done. Then pop to your `rootViewController`

If you are using UINavigationController, Just present your login controller on `NavigationController's` `RootViewController` as like below

```
-(void)logoutNotification
{
logout = YES;
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (logout)
    {        
        AuthController * auth = [[AuthController alloc] init];

        [self presentViewController:auth animated:NO completion:^{

        }];

        logout = NO;

        auth = nil;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is a bit dummy way to do it, but you can simply ALWAYS load the login view and delegate to it the "I'm logged?" check. You can load it hidden or with a waiting sign or whatever... This way you have it already loaded when you logout.

Without seeing your code I can't show you how to, but I guess the logic is enough.